# how to have sql stored procedure query with multiple params can be escaped by using typeORM's method escapeQueryWithParameters

Tags: sql-server, typeorm

escapeQueryWithParameters(sql: string, parameters: ObjectLiteral, nativeParameters: ObjectLiteral)

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/556#issuecomment-317459125 -> here someone in the comments has mentioned how to use in simple query.

```
const [query, parameters] = conn.driver.escapeQueryWithParameters(
    'select a, b from my_table where x between :low and :high',
    { high: 10, low: 2 }
);
conn.manager.query(query, parameters).then(...);
```

But, when i tried with stored procedure with multiple params in the way they have mentioned, it doesn't work!

it throws the following errors,
'Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.'
must declare scalar variable @4

```
  precedingErrors: [
    RequestError: Must declare the scalar variable "@4".
 {
      code: 'EREQUEST',
      number: X,
      lineNumber: X,
      state: X,
      class: X,
      serverName: '',
      procName: '',
      originalError: [Error]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
query is ---> exec [XXX].[dbo].[XXX] @0,'@1', @2, @3, '@4', '@5', '@6', '@7', '@8', '@9'
-- PARAMETERS: ["12345","en","1","20","","","","Name","","ASC"]
```

Answer (score 0):

On the same post someone in the comments below says that in the most recent versions three parameters have to be passed instead of 2.

The final version of the code goes like this :

```
    const [query, parameters] = conn.driver.escapeQueryWithParameters(
        'select a, b from my_table where x between :low and :high',
        { high: 10, low: 2 ,{}}
);
    conn.manager.query(query, parameters).then(...);
```

[Link to said comment](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/556#issuecomment-556042689)